# For loop evaluating if value is in list, unsure why it is returning true/false values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am only about 4 days into python. This course I am going through offers some problems to solve. It is giving true or false correct, I am just unsure how it knows what should be true and false.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

SPY GAME: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order.

```py
def spy_game(nums):
    vals = [0,0,7,'x']
    for num in nums:
        if num == vals[0]:
            vals.pop(0)
    return len(vals) == 1
```

Output

```
spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])
>>True
```

Comment: I am not understanding how it is coming to the true and false. Is the if num == a statement of true and return len(vals) == 1 a return of false?

Comment: `values` is not declared

Comment: `len(vals) == 1` is an expression which evaluates to `True` if both sides are equal and `False` otherwise. The result of this expression is returned by the function.

Comment: No, `len(vals) == 1` is true or false depending on... whether the length of vals is one or not. Assuming you fix the typo just mentioned.

Comment: Generally: peers of tutors are better at explaining - it is not what SO is targetted to do - this might be the reason you get down- and closevoted fast. SO does not teach how to code, it is more of a fix-it institution. You can use it to research problems you have but unless its a good one (see [ask] / [mcve]) your question gets closed or dupe'd fast. A good first step is to thouroughly debug your code - see  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

added some comments to clear things a bit.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    vals = [0,0,7,'x']
    # iterates through every number in the list, in this case it's called nums 
    for num in nums:
    # checks if num is equal to the first index in vals
        if num == values[0]:
    # if the previous check is true, it deletes the first element from the vals list and this means we know that this list contains a 0 so vlas would be [0,7,'x']

            vals.pop(0)
    # the for loop continues until it iterates through all num in nums.
    # becasue 'x' is not a number, the previous conidition in the for loop will never be True for 'x' and 'x' will never be deleted
    # if the sequence of vals is in the nums list , that means only 'x' is left in vals list , which makes the next statement True otherwise it will return False
    return len(vals) == 1

Output

spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])
>>True
```

hope I made it clearer for u.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the first value of `vals` is in `nums`, it removes it from `vals`. That means the second one is now first. It now checks it against the next value of `nums`. So if the values of `nums` show up in the same order as the values of `vals`, every value of val will have been removed, except `"x"`. The last line returns if the amount of items in `vals` is `1` (only `"x"` left or not), which corresponds to whether there were the same numbers in the same order or not.